# How can I deal with Coupon database design?

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have create a simple e-commerce via Laravel, and have some questions about COUPON database design, what I need as follows:

1- I need a normal coupon for checkout (when the user adds all products that he needs then put the coupon this will discount from the total price ). I'm done with this:

```
 Schema::create('coupons', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->bigIncrements('id');
        $table->string('code');
        $table->enum('type', ['percentage', 'numeric']);
        $table->integer('value');
        $table->integer('count')->nullable();
        $table->date('expired_at');
        $table->timestamps();
  });
```

2- I need to put a discount on products of a single category (to put a discount on the whole products that belong to the T-Shirt category).

```
How the design structure of this point?
```

3- I need to put a discount on a specific product or products that I want to put on it.

```
How the design structure of this point?
```

> Could anyone pls help me with this? So confused!

Update:

products table:

```
id - name - price - quantity - category_id - brand_id - created_at
```

categories table

```
 id - category_name - created_at
```

Orders table

```
id - status - user_id - address_id - coupon_id - created_at
```

order_product pivot table

```
order_id - product_id - quantity
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Very interesting! I think may be a good approach should be a pivot table with a polymorphic relation. Somthing like this:

```
id - couponable_type - couponable_id - coupon_id - "whatever_data"
------------------------------------------------------------------
1  - category        - 1             - 1         - ....
2  - order           - 1             - 2         - ....
3  - product         - 1             - 1         - ....
```

Comment: What will this table do?

Comment: You can relation and reuse coupons with categories, products or orders, as you ask on point 2 & 3. Or if you don't want to reuse coupons, you can added the polymorphic relation on the coupons. May I don't understand something? Because other wise, why not added coupon_id on the categories or products?

Comment: So what will be the relation if I use polymorphic ( One To Many or One To One or Many To Many (Polymorphic) ??

Comment: Interesting..... It depends if you reuse or not.... If you don't reuse one to one. It's better not over-engineering... In case your requirement change, add it the many to many and change the schema.

Comment: now each order has one coupon | also all products in one category has one coupon | last one each product  I don't know what should I make it one to one or many to many?!

Answer (score 0):

Since the **COUPON ** has a relation by default with **PRODUCTS**, it will be great to make some relationship, like so:

- Does the **product** will have one **coupon** or many?
- Does the **coupon** will belong to one **product** or many?

I think it's good to give **product ability to use many **coupons** and the **coupon** FOR SURE will belong to many products. In that case, you should add Many To Many Relationship between coupons and products.

The same thing with **products** and **categories**, the product should have many categories and the later should have or belong to many **products.

If you go with that approach you can achieve the Points **01** and **02** easily. You can then create coupons then attach them to specific product or products, or a product category.

To list the coupons of a product or category, you can do something like this:

```php
$product_coupons = Product::findOrFail($id)->coupons;
$category_coupons = ProductCategory::findOrFail($id)->coupons;
```

In Blade you access the coupons like this:

```php
@foreach($product->coupons as $coupon)
{{ $coupon->code }}
@endforeach
```

But @Nahuelsgk approach is a good one, advanced but it's clean, I think it's better to use **[polymorphic](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#polymorphic-relationships)**

Comment: thank you so much for this expansion! that's mean I have to create pivot table many to many relation like this ( coupon_category , coupon_product ) ?

Comment: Yes, but don't forget to add relationships in each Model: Coupon, Category, and Product, but if you go with Polymorphism, you will need just one.

Comment: So pls what if I go with Polymorphism what I need many to many or one to one or what exactly one I need ?

Comment: Use Many To Many [Polymorphic Many To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many-polymorphic-relations)